# How do I create a custom list definition based on a Discussion Board?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've been trying to create a list definition based on the SharePoint Discussion Board in SharePoint 2010, but obviously not successful. I should note that I want to put this list definition in a Visual Studio 2010 SharePoint project.

I've tried to save an existing list as a template, but didn't find any way to import that into the Visual Studio project.

I've tried to just create a list definition in Visual Studio using the new wizards/designers for SharePoint 2010, but it doesn't allow me to base my list on a Discussion Board.

I've also tried to create a custom Content Type based on a Discussion Board and then create a list definition from that Content Type, but the end result when I deploy it is a list that is a Custom List and not a Discussion Board.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. It appears that the new wizards/designers don't support this in 2010 for Discussion Boards. I've done this by doing the following:

1. Created a content type based on the 
   Discussion Board
2. Created a list definition based on
   this content type
3. I then had to change some of the
   values generated for the list
   definition (Elements.xml) so that it
   is treated as a Discussion Board
   instead of a Custom List

   ```
   Type="108"
   BaseType="0"
   ...
   Image="/_layouts/images/itdisc.png"/>
   ```
4. I then changed the schema.xml so
   that it matched the OOB values for
   the FieldRef's, Views, Forms, and
   also had to add the Message content
   type

I'm still working on my customizations...

Comment: I second that question - how did this go?